# Npgsql with Pgbouncer on Kubernetes - hight latency

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, npgsql

I have an identity api, the project is more or less the starter template with Aspnet core identity.  It's deployed on a GKE cluster and use Google Cloud sql PostgresSql as database.

My jmeter test:  6000 requests in 30 seconds on api `Account/LogIn`; db with **5 million** of users

***Using the internal poller of npgsql with connection string `Pooling=true;Minimum Pool Size=100;Maximum Pool Size=500`***

| P99 | P95 | AVG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 700 ms | 80 ms | 40 ms |

The result is good but during the test the pod's cpu is close to 100%

**Using one PgBouncer in the  connection string with `Pooling=false`**

| P99 | P95 | AVG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 53.22s | 48.39s | 9s |

the numbers speak for themselves

Looking on the postgres logs it's seems that  the query parse and bind took 256ms  and after the query execution   the connection was closed after 589 ms.

Am I missing some npgsql configuration ?
why are there a parse and a bind for every query ?

```
[2186] => queryPerProcess Object
        (
            [numQuery] => 4
            [pidProcess] => 6030
            [processStartTime] => 2021-02-17 16:07:10.437
            [totalQueryTime] => 0.338
            [lastQueryTime] => 2021-02-17 16:07:10.438
            [discardQueryTime] => 2021-02-17 16:07:12.006
            [closeTimeDiff] => 568
            [lines] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6030 2021-02-17 16:07:10.437 UTC identity Identity LOG:  duration: 0.112 ms  parse <unnamed>: SELECT a."Id" ... etc"

                    [1] => 6030 2021-02-17 16:07:10.438 UTC identity Identity LOG:  duration: 0.144 ms  bind <unnamed>: SELECT a."Id" .. etc "

                    [2] => 6030 2021-02-17 16:07:10.438 UTC identity Identity LOG:  duration: 0.039 ms  execute <unnamed>: SELECT a."Id" .. etc"

                    [3] => 6030 2021-02-17 16:07:12.006 UTC identity Identity LOG:  duration: 0.043 ms  statement: DISCARD ALL

                )

        )
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be multiple questions there...

First, Npgsql's pool is an in-process pool, where the overhead of opening and closing is extremely small. With PgBouncer your application still has to establish a TCP connection (and possibly even an SSL one), which is a non-negligible overhead. So it's generally recommended to leave Npgsql's pooling on even if you intend to also use pg_bouncer (which can be useful as a server-side pool).

Second, if you're not preparing your statements in anyway, Npgsql sends Parse/Bind/Describe/Execute/Sync for every query. You probably want to take look at the [Npgsql docs on preparation](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/prepare.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Shay, I asked that because, as I said, I'm using the default net core project with aspnet core  identity, so the signin manager does all the work. The load tests with Npgsql's pooling had high CPU consumption in addition to using all available connections.  Are you saying that I can use the pgbouncer as host in the connection string, leaving polling true? My configuration is like this one in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57759603/npgsql-with-pgbouncer-on-kubernetes-pooling-keepalives. If one api takes all the connection I will never be able to scale

Comment: Yes: leave Npgsql's pooling on - as recommended in the link you posted - and connect to pg_bouncer if that's what you need.